# How to create a time variable

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4, nco, ncl

I have a lot of netCDF files where they created from tif files using python gdal library. 
I want to merge each of these files in an large nc file, but they don't have a time variable.

I tried the method described [here](http://dvalts.io/data/modelling/2018/01/16/NetCDF-merging.html) but when I'm going to see the timestamps of each band of the resulted large nc file, it is zeros for all the files.

Moreover, the result of `ncdump -h name-of-the-file` is as following.

```
netcdf g2_BIOPAR_VCI_201701010000_AFRI_PROBAV_V1.0.h5_trans {
dimensions:
        lon = 10081 ;
        lat = 8961 ;
variables:
        char crs ;
                crs:grid_mapping_name = "latitude_longitude" ;
                crs:long_name = "CRS definition" ;
                crs:longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0. ;
                crs:semi_major_axis = 6378137. ;
                crs:inverse_flattening = 298.257223563 ;
                crs:spatial_ref = "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]" ;
                crs:GeoTransform = "-30 0.008927685745461759 0 40 0 -0.008927575047427742 " ;
        double lat(lat) ;
                lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
                lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
                lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        double lon(lon) ;
                lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
                lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
                lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        byte Band1(lat, lon) ;
                Band1:long_name = "GDAL Band Number 1" ;
                Band1:_Unsigned = "true" ;
                Band1:valid_range = 0s, 255s ;
                Band1:_FillValue = 0b ;
                Band1:VCI_CLASS = "DATA" ;
                Band1:VCI_MISSING_VALUE = 251 ;
                Band1:VCI_NB_BYTES = "Uint8" ;
                Band1:VCI_OFFSET = -5 ;
                Band1:VCI_ORDER_BYTES = 1 ;
                Band1:VCI_PRODUCT = "VCI" ;
                Band1:VCI_SCALING_FACTOR = 0.5f ;
                Band1:grid_mapping = "crs" ;

// global attributes:
                :GDAL_ARCHIVE_FACILITY = "VITO" ;
                :GDAL_CENTRE = "VITO" ;
                :GDAL_ELLIPSOID_NAME = "WGS84" ;
                :GDAL_GEODATE_NAME = "WGS84" ;
                :GDAL_INSTRUMENT_ID = "VGT3" ;
                :GDAL_LAT = 40 ;
                :GDAL_LONG = -30 ;
                :GDAL_OTHER = "GLS" ;
                :GDAL_OVERALL_QUALITY_FLAG = "OK" ;
                :GDAL_PIXEL_SIZE = "1km" ;
                :GDAL_PRODUCT = "Mars VCI data" ;
                :GDAL_PRODUCT_ALGORITHM_VERSION = 1. ;
                :GDAL_PRODUCT_TIME = "2017-01-12" ;
                :GDAL_PROJECTION_NAME = "PlateCarree" ;
                :GDAL_REGION_NAME = "AFRI" ;
                :GDAL_SATELLITE = "PROBAV" ;
                :GDAL_TEMPORAL_NOMINAL = "2017-01-01" ;
                :GDAL_TEMPORAL_START = "2017-01-01" ;
                :GDAL_TEMPORAL_STOP = "2017-01-10" ;
                :Conventions = "CF-1.5" ;
                :GDAL = "GDAL 2.3.3, released 2018/12/14" ;
                :history = "Mon Feb 24 14:29:37 2020: GDAL CreateCopy( ../2017/20170101/g2_BIOPAR_VCI_201701010000_AFRI_PROBAV_V1.0.h5_trans.nc, ... )" ;
```

What I want to do is to create a time variable, which will be the same as the global variable: GDAL_TEMPORAL_STOP and merge each file in one large nc file. Ideally I prefer to do this in python. I assume there might be some way to copy the `global variable:GDAL_TEMPORAL_STOP = "2017-01-10" ;` and copy it as time variable for every file, but I couldn't find a way to do it, so this is where I need your help.

Answer (score 1):

The NCO tool for this is [ncecat](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncecat):

```
ncecat -u time in1.nc out1.nc
ncap2 -s 'time[$time]=1;' out1.nc
```

Do that in a loop over files, and then concatenate together with `ncrcat`:

```
ncrcat out*.nc final_out.nc
```

However, `GDAL_TEMPORAL_STOP` is an attribute that it is a character array (aka a string), it is not a variable. You probably want a numeric value for time. This complicates things, and I unfortunately do not have time to provide a full answer as I just noticed you prefer Python anyway so I'll just leave it here. Good luck.